# Change database connection in visual studio from server database to local db temporarily

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015

I'm using database in server in my asp.net mvc web application. Now, i want to use the database in my local db temporarily. What changes do i have to do?

Comment: Change your connection string?

Comment: you should post a snippet of your code

Comment: Change your connection string in the web.config

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your connection string in the web.config file

for your reference posting sample local connection string below

```
  <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-ProfileSearch-20170215151903;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-ProfileSearch-20170215151903.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Comment: Welcome Coderstech. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Change you connection string and replace `DataSource = [db Name]` to `DataSource = LocalDB`.

That's all.